# Pasting text with line-breaks into Visio shape strips line-breaks

Tags: microsoft-visio-2016

In Visio 2016 I can't figure out how to paste text into a shape and retain line breaks.

To reproduce:

- Create a shape or text box in Visio.
- Copy some multi-line text from Excel or a text file.
- Paste it into the Visio shape.

All the line breaks are lost (although text will wrap).

Does anyone have a fix? I couldn't find one on an extensive search.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

- Paste the text into Notepad (or Notepad++).
- Select all and copy.
- Paste into the Visio text box.

I'm not sure why I was having trouble with the text file mentioned in the question.